# How to run the c# exe application without having VS open

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services

I am working with visual studio 2013 in c#. My application contains three project in the same folder: client side, database side and web service side.

When I run the application from within visual studio, it runs very well and all the features of the application are functioning. When I run the exe file located in the bin/debug folder, it runs only when VS is open. If VS is closed it runs only the client side and a message is shown

> impossible to connect to the server.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to host your web service somewhere (e.g. IIS)

Answer (score 1):

When VS is open, it runs the server/web service, and your client.  Running it from the commandline will require starting your server and web service side manually, and then starting the client.

Comment: the problem that i dont know how to start the server and the web service manually!!!

Comment: We will need a bit more information on your setup to help you with starting the server and your web service.

Comment: the problem is that i dont know how to host or deploy the webservice even i dont know how to run iis

Answer (score 0):

To start IIS from the IIS manager go to Run (press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), and type in `inetmgr`.
This will open IIS manager, from there you can start it (forgive me for not being too specific, I don't have it currently installed. I believe you have a Start button at the side-panel. I hope someone in the comments could chime in or just edit this answer. If not I will install & update later).

After it is on you should be then able to run your executable successfully.

---

If your command-line can't find `inetmgr`, see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25338570/825637).
However if you do want to have the IIS manager you can install it + other IIS features easily:

Go to Computer → Uninstall or change a program.
At the side click on "Turn WIndows features on or off".
Inside "Internet Information Services" have your pick of whatever you want.

Comment: thank you. but a message is showen "windows dont find inetmgr, verify that you enter a correct name

Comment: I see, you may not have the manager installed (just IIS). I'll write another answer that should suit you. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

When you run in Visual Studio 2013, by default it uses its IIS Express as a webserver. You can set it to use IIS instead. (If you don't already have IIS installed, you'll need to install it using add/remove Windows components etc--google for more info on that if needed. Make sure you drill down to include ASP.NET under the IIS bits and pieces.)

To use IIS instead of the Visual Studio development webserver, right-click the project in Solution Explorer, and click the Web tab:

[image]

---

Select <kbd>External Host</kbd> in the dropdown, and enter a URL such as `http://localhost/WebApp1`. This is the virtual name by which IIS will access the files in your project folder. Earlier versions of Visual Studio included a button to create the virtual directory, but in 2013 you must create it yourself by running IIS Manager:

[image]

---

Enter the same virtual name you use in the project settings, and the physical path of your project:

[image]

---

Finally, right-click the newly created virtual directory and choose `Convert to Application`.

The website/webservice will now run under IIS, so will be available independently of Visual Studio.

Comment: it dosent appear like that. i am using vs 2013 and the web tab dosent be showen!!

Comment: Ah yes. I'll replace it with 2013 info now.

Comment: where? i didnt find any thinh??

Comment: The question now starts "When you run in Visual Studio **2013**", and all the info and pictures are for 2013. Maybe a cache problem if you're not seeing the new version? Try clearing browser cache & temporary internet files. or using another machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have IIS manager installed you can launch IIS directly from `iisexpress.exe`.
It should be in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe`, so just go ahead and run it.

Then you should be able to run your application.

Comment: even when i run the iisexpress.exe, i run the application .exe and the same problem appears!!!

Comment: @ADAM Could you tell us which web platform you are using? maybe you have some other dependency (other than IIS).